# SFINAE problems with std::begin

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

The following code works in Visual Studio 2013 but fails to compile with clang or gcc so I am guessing it is not valid c++.

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template< typename T >
class SupportsStdBegin
{
  // std::false_type TestHasBegin( ... ) always exists.
  template< typename >
  static std::false_type TestSupportsBegin( ... );
  // std::true_type TestHasBegin( int ) only exists if std::begin( T() ) is a valid expression.
  template< typename U >
  static auto TestSupportsBegin( int ) -> decltype( std::begin( std::declval< T >() ), std::true_type{ } );

public:
  static const bool value = decltype( TestSupportsBegin< T >( 0 ) )::value;
};

static_assert( !SupportsStdBegin< int >::value, "'int' does not support std::begin()." );

const int TestArray[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, };
static_assert( SupportsStdBegin< decltype( TestArray ) >::value, "'const int TestArray[]' supports std::begin()." );

static_assert( SupportsStdBegin< std::vector< int > >::value, "'std::vector< int >' supports std::begin()." );
```

Can someone explain why [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) doesn't work as I'm expecting it to?

The line containing `decltype( std::begin( std::declval< T >() )` fails for the `static_assert` for `int` type with the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int)'
```

I thought that this would mean SFINAE would fail and the implementation returning `std::false_type` would be used to set `SupportsStdBegin< T >::value`.

I understand there are alternate ways of writing this test but I would like to know why this particular way is not valid. I've successfully used it before to test if member functions exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SFINAE to occur, the expression needs to be dependent on a template parameter in the *immediate context* of the template, i.e. the template parameter list.

The easy fix is to default `U` to `T` and use `U` in your dependent expression:

```
template <typename U=T>
static auto TestSupportsBegin( int ) 
    -> decltype( std::begin( std::declval< U >() ), std::true_type{ } );
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bf6b878ffa63d70)

Comment: Doh! I wrote the wrong template parameter in the std::begin expression. Thanks for catching that so quickly. Annoying that MSVC doesn't see that as a problem.